# mantain CLIPS running when asserting new facts

Tags: clips

It's possible to keep CLIPS running while asserting new facts?

[example of execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG73q.png)

It would be possible not to have to make (run) to test this program after each assert command? I mean, making only one (run) and then, fire the rules automatically when i insert new facts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use helper functions to perform both the assertion and the subsequent run:

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> 
(deffunction push (?value)
   (assert-string (str-cat "(push-value " ?value ")"))
   (run))
CLIPS> 
(deffunction assert* (?value)
   (assert-string ?value)
   (run))
CLIPS> 
(defrule push-to-stack
   ?s <- (stack $?stack)
   ?p <- (push-value ?v)
   =>
   (println "Pushing value " ?v)
   (retract ?s ?p)
   (assert (stack ?v ?stack)))
CLIPS> (assert (stack))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (push 3)
Pushing value 3
CLIPS> (assert* "(push-value 4)")
Pushing value 4
CLIPS>
```

For testing, you can also create a file containing the commands (as follows), and then use the batch command to automatically execute all the commands in your file.

```
(assert (stack))
(assert (push-value 3))
(assert (run))
(assert (push-value 4))
(run)
(assert (push-value 9))
(assert (push-value 2))
(run)
```

Comment: Thanks gary. You are my CLIPS "guru".